# undefined method `get_taxonomies' when using a custom theme extension in 1.3?

Tags: spree

i use the following gemfile:

```
gem 'spree_gateway', :github => 'spree/spree_gateway'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch => 'edge'
gem 'spree_theme_v1', :path => '../spree_theme_v1'
```

when using the last "spree_theme_v1" gem i created using the command "spree extension theme_v1", i can't browse the login and the account route anylonger. instead i get the following error message:

**NoMethodError in Spree/user_sessions#new - undefined method `get_taxonomies' for**

the error comes from the file views/spree/shared/_main_nav_bar.html.erb which i overwrite in my extension. as soon as i remove the file it works again. any advice, why this isn't working? or do i have to overwrite another file?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the gem is not loading the products_helper.rb from spree: https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/core/app/helpers/spree

You can make it work adding `helper 'spree/products'` to the controller that is failing (something about devise in your case).

I 'll show you my redefined PagesController from spree_essential_cms, maybe it helps:

```
class Spree::PagesController < Spree::BaseController
  helper 'spree/products'
  def show
    ...
  end
end
```

As noted here http://osdir.com/ml/spree-user/2013-01/msg00053.html you can also make a decorator in app/controllers and call it something like add_products_helper_decorator.rb, and then fill it with this content:

```
[Spree::UserPasswordsController, Spree::UserRegistrationsController, Spree::UserSessionsController].each do |klass|  
    klass.class_eval do    
      helper 'spree/products'  
    end
 end
```

That should be enough to require that helper into the right places and make it available for you.